# add content to top portion of a UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In the *Interface Builder* you can drag a UI element (such as a `UITextField`) to a *grouped* `UITableView` and it allows you to *attach* that view to the top or bottom of the table.

How can I do this programmatically? (also, what is this called?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView has tableHeaderView and tableFooterView properties you can set.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the textField as the headerView or Footer view of the tableView.